# How to Set android:textColor using drawable in Android?

Tags: android, drawable, textcolor

I know how to set a drawable as the color of the text using xml but I don't know how it is done in Java.

In xml is something like this:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/selected_color"
```

in JAVA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "drawable" you mean a selector with color items, you should refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678694/how-to-set-textcolor-using-settextcolorcolorsstatelist-colors).

You won't be able to use the textcolor with image drawables, or selectors containing image drawables.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that by "drawable" you mean a selector with color items like this:

res/color/your_colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffffff"/>
    <item android:color="#ff1c5fab"/>
</selector>
```

You can use this code: `mText.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_colors));`

Answer (score 5):

color/selector_colors.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_activated="true" />

    <item android:color="@color/black" />

</selector>
```

you have to implement it into textview like that:

```
textview.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector_colors));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=android%20set%20text%20color%20programmatically&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thetekblog.com%2F2010%2F01%2Fandroid-programmatically-setting-the-text-colour%2F&ei=xnXKTviOFcynsQKipYHfAg&usg=AFQjCNFq9DnqLGF6cMAou2U_T1vtJbi2yA), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310603/android-how-to-programmatically-set-button-color),  or [this](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/93a43d789e6419a0) ?

The last link says to use:

```
tvImagesTitle.setTextColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.blue) );
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use HTML:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
text.append("<font color='").append(selectedColor).append("'>")                     .append("your text here").append("</font>");

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.toString()), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

> res/color/selector_colors.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffffff"/>
    <item android:color="#ff1c5fab"/>
</selector>
```

You can directly use this code:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/selector_colors"
android:text="click" />
```